Doctrine is fetching a ManyToOne self-referencing attribute with EXTRA_LAZY
I'm having a performance issue with non-needed SQL queries (Symfony 5.4, Doctrine 2, Elasticsearch 6.1.1, FosElastica 5.2)
Here are an extract of the concerned entities :
class Etablissement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Etablissement", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="geres", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gestionnaire_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $gestionnaire; // The manager of this Etablissement, can be NULL

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Etablissement", mappedBy="gestionnaire", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"type" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $geres; // All the managed Etablissements

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="TexteReferencement", mappedBy="etablissement", cascade={"persist"}) */
    protected $texteReferencement; // can be NULL

}

class TexteReferencement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Etablissement", inversedBy="texteReferencement", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="etablissement_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     */
    private $etablissement;
}

I'm using Elastica to get a list of Etablissement then display only the id. This is an example of the result :



Id
Gestionnaire




ET075-183
NULL


ET075-341
GE075-46


ET075-403
NULL


ET075-469
GE075-103



The problem is Doctrine generates some extra SQL queries :
SELECT * FROM texte_referencement t0 WHERE t0.etablissement_id = 'GE075-46';
SELECT * FROM texte_referencement t0 WHERE t0.etablissement_id = 'GE075-103';

I'd like to get rid of thoes usesless queries since I don't need data from texte_referencement
Maybe I'm wrong but this is my understanding of the workflow :

Elastica hydrates the Etablissement entity set
Since each Etablissement have a manager, Doctrine loads the manager of each Etablissement (if exists)
Since each Etablissement have a TexteReferencement, Doctrine loads the data for each manager

But this seems non-sence :

using fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" should not run step #2
why do step #3 concerns only managed Etablissement ?

